# Packaging a python script with an Electron.js App

Tags: python-3.x, windows, electron, electron-packager

I'm new to Electron and I have built this calculator app using electron.js and python.

The way in which the app works is that whenever the '=' button is clicked in the UI , the electron app sends the equation to a python script which computes and returns the value to the UI . The communication between electron and python happens through standard input/output streams .So far, I have achieved this flow.

I don't know how to package this electron app along with this python script using electron packager.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance !